# How to dump process list during CPU spike or Memory spike in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, memory, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

My machine is a Windows 10 and it freezes for 2 mins, which is really disruptive. The things is that everything is so slow I don't get to see list of process in order to investigate further.

1. What is the best way capture the process causing the issue?
2. Based on what factors do I need to filter the process list in order to find the troublesome process? (From previous experience, I know I should be looking at the memory usage and CPU usage while spikes happen. Please let me know what else I should be looking at?)

I have used `prefmon` to find the time of CPU and memory peaks. I am more curious to find a way to find the troublesome process. One simple trick I did is that I scheduled a job to dump `tasklist` output into a text file every minute. But, I could see the scheduled job was NOT running for 3-4 minutes when the peaks were happening.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to crash the entire machine and get a "Full" memory dump when you know it's hung.

You should setup the computer in advance to initialize a crash from the keyboard by following this KBA:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545499(v=vs.85).aspx

You also need to configure the computer to create a full dump. A quick Google came up with:

- https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/111474

Either way I'll assume at this point you can get a memory.dmp file when the computer was in the hung state, then you can:

1. [Download the Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) in order to install just the Debugging Tools component. This will get you `Windbg` i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe`
2. Launch `Windbg` and load in the dump file. "File" → "Open Crash dump".
3. Now this is where it can get heavy, but if you want just a easy to use process tree you can use [an extension called DbgKit](http://www.andreybazhan.com/dbgkit.html). To use it, copy the 64-bit dll into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\`
4. In `Windbg`, load the extension using the following command:

   ```
   .load dbgkit
   ```

   The following command will show that it's loaded:

   ```
   .chain
   ```
5. You can then run:

   ```
   !dbgkit.ps
   ```

This will give you a Process Explorer-type view of the dump so you can see what the processes were doing.  It will take a while to extract various information but it will give you what you're after.

Hopefully this will be a good start.  Beyond this I would suggest reviewing a few videos in [*The Defrag Tools* series on Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools) on how to debug a memory dump for a hang.

Comment: I just hope the machine would crash as soon as you press the manual crash shortcut keys... not after the freeze cleared the pipeline.