# How to diagnose frozen Win10 login screen?

Tags: windows-10, boot, freeze

My PC was freezing 90% of attempts at Win10 login screen, so I installed fresh Win10 Home x64 from USB and STILL freezes 10% of the time.

I have tried using Event Viewer to see system-level events during bootup. I meticulously timed events with a stopwatch while my PC failed to start windows twice in a row but was disappointed to see a 2 minute gap in events between when I started the whole process, and after the third (successful) startup attempt. Thus no events shown from when windows login splash freezes, won't lift up to reveal login input, or the second attempt when I got a black screen with working cursor, but no key/mouseclick response.

Any way for me to view what my system is doing when it locks up? Windows screen usually just freezes, i.e. clock doesn't update in lowerleft and wifi sign doesn't show connection in bottom right.

Surely there has to be a way for me to see what my CPU is doing before it crashes, right?

Comment: My reply here is valid for this scenario:
http://superuser.com/questions/1169951/how-to-dump-process-list-during-cpu-spike-or-memory-spike-in-windows-10/1169959#1169959

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this when Windows 10 was first released. I'm doubtful it's the same issue but I'll explain anyway.

There was a bug on that login screen in one of the early updates for win10 that would cause your screen to freeze or go black at the login screen. The thing is, it was still running fine otherwise. So I could hit the up key, type in my password, and hit enter; and I would still be logged in with a perfectly functioning system. No longer frozen and with another update that came out rather soon after I experienced the bug, it wasn't more than a minor annoyance.